# Details of new SoilGrid data on GEE unclear

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am processing the new 250m resolution, 6 depths (0-5cm, 5-15cm...) data of the ISRIC Soil Grids on GEE, for my region of interest. Currently only the mean prediction is available on GEE for different soil properties. However, I am unclear whether this is what is called 'Latest' data which is continously changing based on new data or the'Snapshot' data which is for July 2016 and Sept 2019? If it is the 'Snapshot' data, which is it July 2016 or Sept 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "Latest" at the time the product was made, currently May 2020, see https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids, but also includes some points that can not be published in WoSIS due to data license but can be used for mapping in SoilGrids.  This will be regularly updated. The WoSIS "snapshot"s is dated and will note change, the WoSIS "latest" is continuously updated.
-- David Rossiter
-- Guest Researcher, ISIRC

p.s. Also you can access SoilGrids directly via REST, see the info. page